# Filter output is a JSON ids, these ids should be copied in to another json

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am filtering 2 json files contains ids and picking up non existing ids.
results some output to filter with list of ids, these ids should be copied to other json or next activity to copy data from rest API using these ids.

Comment: Hi @shanucnu8888, Can you please provide sample input and expected output and pipeline snips that you have tried?

Comment: Task is to compare 2 JSON files and extract different ids from FROM JSON 2.
Ex: Json1
{"id":"017d0a61-ce2f"}
{"id":"017d0a53-b5f8"}
Json2
{"id":"017d0a53-b5f9"}
{"id":"017d0a53-b5f8 "}
Comparing both json and get the different id

My case
Using lookup for json1 and iterate each id and inside foreach checking with json2 using lookup and filtering the non contain records.
But unable capture records generated by filter;
EX: 
Output
Copy to clipboard
{ 
"ItemsCount": 1531, 
"FilteredItemsCount": 3, 
"Value": 
[ 
{ "id": "fa39b318-726b " }, 
{ "id": "e523fb9c-0606 " } 
]
 }

Comment: Or suggest any other way to compare 2 json which contains ids

Answer (score 0):

I have reproed with sample JSON files. Below is the filter output.

[image]

Use the below expression to use the output value of filter activity in later activities or you can create a variable and store the value in that variable using set variable activity and use it later.

Here I created a string variable to store the output.

Expression:

`@string(activity('Filter1').output.value)`

[image]

Set variable output:

[image]